# IIB SOAP Input to MQ

Tags: soap, mq

I need to transform a very simple soap message that contains CDATA into an MQ message and send it to a queue. I am sending the message correctly, but the HTTPInputHeader end up in the message queue along with the message payload. All I want in the message queue is that one CDATA section, not the headers. There should be a way to remove them in a mapping node. IIB10

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPHeader Node allows you to remove the HTTPInputHeader

Answer (score 0):

Using ESQL the input data can be converted in to a json and store the json in the queue.

```
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data = InputRoot.XMLNSC.(XMLNSC.Element)*[1];
```